# Using the "groups" feature of the people app in ICS (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android, contacts

With ICS, we have seen a cool API for the people application (previous contact). That allows you to create "groups" and add a contact to them.

There is a demo that has been updated: SampleSyncAdapter: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

and that works pretty well. Contacts are created from a webservice, and added to contacts from ICS.

Unfortunately, as I would like to go a step further and use these groups, the Sample project is a lot of line of code and XML files, I cannot find where is the part specific to ICS.

I used this demo: https://github.com/c99koder/AndroidSyncProviderDemo that add a contact called "Elmer Fudd" and is well written.

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to adapt this project for ICS "groups".

Here is a snippet on how we add a contact:

```
private static void addContact(Account account, String name, String username) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Adding contact: " + name);
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, username);
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.c99.SyncProviderDemo.profile");
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, username);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "SyncProviderDemo Profile");
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "View profile");
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    try {
        mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will answer myself :-p

```
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI); 
builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);    
builder.withValue(GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, ensureSampleGroupExists(context,account)); 
builder.withValue(GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);  
operationList.add(builder.build());
```